# Select from list of values on beeline

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, beeline

I use beeline, which is a JDBC client based on SQLLine, to run Hive queries.
I would like to select from a liste of values like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (a,b,b,c,d,..z)
```

is that posssible?

Comment: likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564956/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-sql-server

Comment: @arhak I already try this but it doesn't work

Comment: ok, not the exact same scenario perhaps, a little variation would make the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT 12
    UNION SELECT 23
    UNION SELECT 34
    UNION SELECT 12
    UNION SELECT 23
) AS t1;
```

PS: also refer to very closely related question [How can I select from list of values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564956/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-sql-server)

Comment: Is there something like `select * from  [a,b,c,d,e, f...z]` because I have a lot of values and it painful to write such a query

Comment: `DISTINCT` is superfluous here. A`UNION` operation  always returns unique rows. But, a `UNION ALL`  with `DISTINCT` would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `stack`, it works much faster than UNION:

```
hive> select id from
    > (
    > select stack(5, --the number of elements
    > 10 ,
    > 20 ,
    > 30 ,
    > 40 ,
    > 50
    > ) as (id)
    > )s;
OK
10
20
30
40
50
Time taken: 4.88 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Comment: is that work in beeline? have you never tried in beeline?

Comment: @hisi unfortunately  I cannot check beeline right now

Comment: That doesn't seem working!! I've just tried in beeline

Answer (score 0):

You may try `split` and `explode`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
 (
 select explode( split('a,b,b,c,d,e,f' ,',')) c
 ) as t
 ORDER BY c
```