# SQL to repeat rows from a specific year to current year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a following table,

```
Code    Desc    Curr_Year
-------------------------
AB      XYZ     2019
```

And I am looking for a SQL query which repeats the same row from year 1993 to 2019.

The output should look like this:

```
Code    Desc    Curr_Year Inc_Yr
---------------------------------
AB      XYZ     2019      1993
AB      XYZ     2019      1994
AB      XYZ     2019      1995
AB      XYZ     2019      1996
.       .       .         .
.       .       .         .

AB      XYZ     2019      2019
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I am not a SQL expert and really struggling to get this done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write a recursive cte that returns the wanted years. Cross join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like:

```
SELECT Code
      ,Desc
      ,Curr_Year 
      ,g.num as Inc_Yr
  FROM yourtable A
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 26 1992+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) as num FROM sys.all_objects) g
```

In a first step generating a list of values of all years you need, then a simple `CROSS JOIN`.

If you are not allowed to use the table `sys.all_objects`, you could still use a list of values. Have a look at the second answer to this question:

[How can I select from list of values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564956/how-can-i-select-from-list-of-values-in-sql-server/27443002)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Esteban.
But is there a way this can be achieved in a only 'Select' statement without declaring any variable as I have to use the query in an application.

Comment: You can always use parameterized queries in your application.

Comment: I am using SAP reporting application which accepts only free hand sql (which is only select statements).

Comment: @Aniket I've just updated my answer to a solution without CTE

Comment: Thats great Esteban. Thank you very much.
It does solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/SSGYE13055)

```
;WITH Years AS
(
  SELECT Inc_Yr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects     
)
SELECT Table1.*, Inc_Yr 
FROM Years 
CROSS JOIN Table1
WHERE Inc_Yr BETWEEN 1993  AND 2019
ORDER BY Inc_Yr;
```